# PHP Cannot loop through nested JSON

Tags: php, json

I have an API which is returning some nested JSON data with multiple levels. My PHP code to loop through is below but I'm not getting any output:

```
    $data = json_decode($output, true);     

    foreach($data as $item){

        $title = $item->events->name->text;
        echo $title;
    }
```

An example of the data can be found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAtrI.png

I am trying to print the text name of each of the events (events->name->text)

Comment: you should use `foreach($data->events as $item){`

Comment: I get a syntax error:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: That's because events is an array collection of objects, not an object. `foreach($data['events'] as $item)`

Comment: you need foreach($data['events'] as $item){} (because you have decoded the json into an associative array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a problem in your code, when you decode the json string, you use:

```
$data = json_decode($output, true);
```

It is converting everything to "array" (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), so you cannot access it like if they were objects.

You have to do:

```
foreach($data as $item){

    $title = $item["events"]["name"]["text"];
    echo $title;
}
```

Hope this helps!